# update table mysql initials name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table with a column for names and I created a new column for just the initials of the name.

Is it possible for me to update this field?

There are 600 users.

Example:
user table

```
name           |  initials  |
-----------------------------
Laisa Madonna  |   LM       |

Joseph Steph   |   JS       |

John W Bush    |   JB       |
```

how could i do that?

example:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nameFull, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)  AS firstName
    ,TRIM( SUBSTR(nameFull, LOCATE(' ', nameFull)) ) AS lastName
FROM
    user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the column in the table, use this update statement:

```
update users
set initials = concat(
  left(name, 1), 
  left(substring_index(name, ' ', -1), 1)  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ooQ3gtEJ7mPbVqgKAYT4kj/0).
Results:

```
| name          | initials |
| ------------- | -------- |
| Laisa Madonna | LM       |
| Joseph Steph  | JS       |
| John W Bush   | JB       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
RENAME TABLE old_table TO new_table;
OR
ALTER TABLE old_table RENAME new_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generated column:

```
alter table user add initials varchar(2) generated always as
     ( concat(left(name), left(substring_index(name, ' ', -1), 1)) );
```

Comment: Hi, my message error:
# 1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to '), left (substring_index (name,' ', -1), 1)))' on line 2